# Setting up a subdomain in IIS?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, iis

I have an existing site that I would like to add a staging subdomain to.  I created a new web site for it in IIS, added a host header for subdomain.mysite.com but when I try to get to the subdomain it is not found.

Do I need to create an A Record in my DNS to point subdomain.mysite.com to the server's IP or will the existing entry for mysite.com work?  If not, can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to create an additional DNS record. Don't think of it having any relation to your primary website, as it is really just another website. This is true both when looking at your DNS configuration and your IIS sites configuration. The thing that might make your primary site seem to be different, is you probably have an entry that points **yourdomain.com** to your sites IP address as well as having the **www.yourdomain.com** record which points to the same place.